# Tomcat 8 migration - How to get response cookies

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, cookies, tomcat8

I'm working on migration from Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 8.

In Tomcat 6 my application uses [Response.getCookies() method](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Response.html#getCookies()).

There is no such method in Tomcat 8. How can I get cookies set for the response?

The only thing I found is cookies could be retrieved from the request by [HttpServletRequest.getCookies() method](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies()).

Comment: What's wrong with using `HttpServletRequest.getCookies`?

Comment: This function retrieves cookies from request. I need a response cookies.

Comment: You added a cookie to the response, and then forgot what it was?

Answer (score 0):

As of Tomcat version 7 you use method `addCookie(Cookie cookie)` of `HttpServletResponse`.

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("name","value")
response.addCookie(c);
```

From Tomcat api docs https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html

> void addCookie(Cookie cookie)
>
> Adds the specified cookie to the response. This method can be called
>   multiple times to set more than one cookie.
>
> Parameters: cookie - the Cookie to return to the client

Comment: I need to get list of cookies, not to add them to the response.

Comment: In that case this may perhaps solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507477/is-there-any-way-to-read-cookies-from-the-response-object-in-java#17706431